# Unable to close as duplicate on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

When I try to close a question as duplicate, it fails at the point where I am to enter the URL of the duplicate. The look up of that URL fails with the message “An error occurred while searching; please try again”. My browser's console shows a request to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/popup/close/search-originals/96669 that's redirected to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/posts/popup/close/search-originals/96669 which returns a 500 status.

This doesn't happen on other sites. It's presumably a bug in rev 2013.9.27.1464. In case this is browser-related, I'm using Chrome 27.0.1453.93.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Must have something to do with that deploy they did this morning....

Comment: Hacking the HTML to change the value of the input and re-enable the submit button manually still works. :)

Comment: it's a sign that there are too many duplicates here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.

The backend parts of flagging and closing dialogs were recently rewritten.  This error was caused because I missed a view that needed to be ported over as part of removing the old code.